# What is an alternative to using 'eval' to accessing a variable by name to "sync" it with another?

Tags: javascript, eval

I want to keep two JavaScript variables in sync when I run a function. The variable that is to be pointed to is in an object. The code I have so far is this:

```
var myname = "bob";
var thevar = "";
var varobj = {tvar: "myname"};
var syncvar = function() {
    thevar = eval(varobj.tvar);
};

syncvar();
alert(thevar); // bob
myname = "eve";
syncvar();
alert(thevar); // eve
```

How can I do something similar to this without using the dreaded eval? Keep in mind that I want this function to be universal i.e. I want it to work with anyone's objects.

Thanks in advance.

Clarification edit: This is client side. I essentially want a variable that is a "pointer" to another variable (maybe not in the strict definition sense). I have made a function which can sync the variables, but it uses eval, which makes me skeptical. The "universal" part is that I can make tvar point to anything which will sync it. For example, if you include the above code, you can then:

```
myage = 20;
varobj = {tvar: "myage"};
syncvar(); 
alert(thevar); // 20
myage = 100;
syncvar();
alert(thevar); // 100
```

Thus making it "universal" as varobj.tvar can "point" to anything to keep it in sync.

Comment: There is no way to have a universal function that syncs variables without using eval here.

Comment: @user2864740: I don't think the edit you made is correct. This goes beyond acceding variables by name, assuming that the target variable should also be accessed by name (that's what I understand by "universal").

Comment: @FelixKling You may be correct. I'm only .. 90% certain. But "in sync" is so broad, and it didn't seem to be employed other than the resulting assignment.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to achieve. Having the variable be hard coded doesn't seem very universal to me. Also, what's the use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setters and getters to make a "virtual" property on the window named `thevar`, which mirrors to `varobj.tvar`:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'thevar', {
    get: function( ) { return window[varobj.tvar]    ; },
    set: function(v) {        window[varobj.tvar] = v; }
});

> varobj = { tvar: "bob" }
> thevar = 1
> bob
< 1
```

Whether or not you really want to do that is another question entirely.

Comment: There was a previous answer here which mentioned using `window[varobj.tvar]` which solves my issue. Thanks for reminding me of it.